# Rebuilding Solution in VS with DTE

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2003, envdte

Lately I have been having a problem with Visual Studio 2003, after a couple of times you run the solution, there will come this one run that will tell me a lot of objects are missing... or that many objects are not available due to their scope.

This problems is solved after a rebuild (which rebuilds the whole solution disregarding if a project has changed or not). Since this is rather often I have assigned a keyboard shortcut to the *Rebuild Solution* option, after this I can run the solution without any problems.

I would now like to take that a step forward and Running the solution automatically after the Rebuild Solution completes. I tried using a macro but, after looking at the generated code:

```
Sub Rebuild()
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.RebuildSolution")
    DTE.Debugger.Go(False)
End Sub
```

I realized that ExecuteCommand is returning as soon as it launches the `Build.RebuildSolution` command and so `DTE.Debuger.Go(False)` cannot execute because the solution is already building.

What I need is a way for *Debugger.Go()* to wait for the *ExecuteCommand* to be completed or for a distinct way to Rebuild the Solution in which the next line won't execute until Rebuild is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have VS2K3, but in later versions the way to do this would be to hook up to the BuildDone event on EnvironmentEvents, as:

```
Private Sub BuildEvents_OnBuildDone( _
    ByVal Scope As EnvDTE.vsBuildScope, _
    ByVal Action As EnvDTE.vsBuildAction) Handles BuildEvents.OnBuildDone

    DTE.Debugger.Go(False)

End Sub
```

You'd probably want to hook up to a variable set in your macro, to ensure that the build event is only handled when the build is initiated from your "Rebuild"

Comment: For those that refer to this question later you may remove the `Handles BuildEvents.OnBuildDone` and manually add the handler like this `AddHandler DTE.Events.BuildEvents.OnBuildDone, AddressOf BuildEvents_OnBuildDone`. Apparently DTE is not declared WithEvents...